# Kubernetes uses dns for nginx proxy_pass but not rewrite

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes

Why does kubernetes (using minikube) use dns for nginx's `proxy_pass` but not rewrite?

Kubernetes replaces `auth-proxy-service.default` with ip address

```
  location /widget-server/ {
    proxy_pass http://auth-proxy-service.default:5902/;
  }
```

kubernetes does not replace `auth-proxy-service.default` with ipaddress and the url in browser actually shows `http://auth-proxy-service.default:5902/foo`

```
  location /form-builder-auth {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://auth-proxy-service.default:5902/foo redirect;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's what a redirect means? Reverse proxies are transparent, redirects are user-facing.